# Calculate accuracy score of kmeans model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

This works as expected and returns 1 for one of the groups.

```
from sklearn import metrics

labels_true = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
labels_pred = [6, 6, 6, 1, 2, 2]

metrics.homogeneity_completeness_v_measure(labels_true, labels_pred)
```

> (1.0, 0.6853314789615865, 0.8132898335036762)

But this returns 0.75 for all 3 groups while I expected "1.0" for one of the groups like the example mentioned above.

```
y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]


labels = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0]


metrics.homogeneity_completeness_v_measure(y, labels)
```

> (0.7514854021988339, 0.7649861514489816, 0.7581756800057786)

Expected 1 in one of the groups above!

---

Update:

As you can see, one of the groups matches with the other and therefore one of the values should have been 1 instead of 0.75 accuracy that I get for all 3 groups. This is not expected!

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(y)
Counter(labels)

Counter({0: 50, 1: 50, 2: 50})
Counter({1: 50, 0: 62, 2: 38})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, homogeneity, completeness and v measure score are calculated as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

C and K are two random variables. In your case, C is the labels true, while K is the label predicted.
If `h = 1`, it means that `H(C|K) = 0`, as `H(C)` is always less than 0. If `H(C|K) = 0`, it means that random variable C is completely determined by given random variable K, you can see more detailed definition on [conditional entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy). So in your first case, why h = 1? Because when I give a value of random variable K (labels predicted), I know what the random variable C (labels true) will be. If k equals 6, I know c is 0. If k is 1, c is 1, etc. So when talking about the second case, why h != 1 or c != 1. Because even though there is a perfect match between 1 to 0, but there are no perfect match for other classes. If I give k is 1, I know c is 0. But when I give k is 0, I'm not sure whether c is 1 or 2. Thus, the homogeneity score or in reverse, completeness score, you can think about that, will not be 1.